# Paypal auto redirect not working

Tags: paypal, wordpress

I'm using wordpress event manager for a registration form. Once user gets registered, user will be redirected to PayPal page. After user pays the subscription fee, I want user to be redirected to my web site. I've enabled auto redirect in paypal "Website Preferences" page. But still it is not redirecting to website after the payment.

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be informed that `Auto Return` feature will only work if the payment is made via **PayPal**.
It does not work if its made via Credit/Debit Card.

Comment: I'm using PayPal sandbox account for testing purpose and I'm paying it through PayPal and not Credit/Debit Card.